# Trying to GET some resource returns net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, loopbackjs, strongloop

So I re-installed my database, the problem is that now, my app doesn't seem to work.

Every time I try to GET a resource in my Angular.js site, the request stalls until I get back this error:

```
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

The preflight "OPTIONS" requests works fine, but the actual GET request just hangs up.

If I try the same GET request with curl, then I instantly get a correct response. The same for the browser, if I type the request in the address bar, I get a correct response.

What do you guys think may be happening here?

Comment: Please include some code where you're making the calls

Comment: It might be firewall, network configuration, headers and a dozen of other reasons. Hard to tell without a minimized test case or more details like how the exact HTTP conversation looks like (with raw HTTP request/response including the preflight in both the working and non-working case).